# gpsd parsing GPRMC data incorrectly

Tags: bluetooth, gps, serial-port, meego

I've connected my Nokia N9 to my linux laptop via bluetooth-serial using the extGPS app from Ovi. Everything seems to work fine im able to connect gpsd to the serial device and get GPS output.
But theres a problem with the GPS output, the longitude is always 0.000E when, in my case the correct GPS longitude should be something like -9.13245

```
gpsd:IO: <= GPS: $GPRMC,184922.0,A,3842.126000,N,0-9-26.781000,E,000.10.0,131.15,211013,,,A*49
gpsd:IO: => client(0): {"class":"TPV","tag":"RMC","device":"/devrfcomm0","mode":3,"time":"2013-10-21T18:50:48.000Z","ept":0.005,"lat":38.702000000,"lon":0.000000000,"alt":74.000,"track":126.0800,"speed":0.000,"climb":0.000}\x0d\x0a
```

The problem might be with gpsd parsing the GPRMC data.
Is there a way to solve this or an alternitive to gpsd in linux ?

Answer (score 0):

The fault is not the gpsd.

Look at the RMC sentence.

```
"$GPRMC,184922.0,A,3842.126000,N,0-9-26.781000,E,000.10.0,131.15,211013,,,A*49"
```

This is garbage! especially: `0-9-26.781000`

What is that? This is not a coordinate, and for sure not in the format as specified in the RMC sentence.

Comment: i noticed that soon after i made this post, unfortunately i haven't found a way to fix this, besides buying a new GPS, nor have i found anyone with the same issue :\
could i perhaps, redirect the output of that serial device, /dev/rfcomm0, thru a script or something and fix the GPRMC string, to another serial device and point gpsd at it ?

Comment: make sure  that the baud settings are correct, try lower speed; strange issue; make sure its not a software bug in reading the io (buffer size, etc)